# C# string validation

Tags: c#, string

I have this code:

```
string[] pa = new string[] { "Maia", "Porto", "Valongo", "Gondomar", "Gaia", "Matosinhos"};

private string[] concelho;

public string[] Concelho
{
     get { return concelho; }
     set { concelho = value; }
 }
```

I need to validate the string `pa` to see if user put one of that values on text box. The validation needs to be case sensitive, can help??

Comment: You can call the `Contains` method of the array.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to validate the string pa to see if user put one of that values
>   on text box.

Simply do this:

```
if(pa.Contains(TextBoxData.Text.ToString())){
// Do something.
}
```

Comment: @un-lucky it is case sesitive

Comment: yes your answer is fine but you need to change `toString()` to `ToString()`.

Comment: @CodingYoshi true, i get mixed up between JAVA and C# every now and then.

Comment: `.Text` will give you a string then what is the significance for `.ToString()` there?

Comment: @os.: not much in this line but will not be a good practice. Since `.Text` gives you a string object you can directly apply them in contains. I don't think `.ToString()` will do anything special here

Answer (score 1):

You can just use Linq and call `Any` method and pass the user entered value to it. It will return `true` if the value is in the array, or it will return false.

```
var isValid = pa.Any(x => x == "uservalue");
```

Make sure you import the Linq namespace by `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @un-lucky what is your point, that will do a case sensitive comparison.

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick for you

```
string[] pa = new string[] { "Maia", "Porto", "Valongo", "Gondomar", "Gaia", "Matosinhos" };
string inpstr = "Maia";
if(pa.Contains(inpstr))
{
    //Your Textbox or Input String is one of the in the List / Array.
}
```

You can use your Textbox.Text instead of `inpstr` and yes it is case sensitive.

Comment: @un-lucky Yes it is case sensitive. :)

Comment: @un-lucky `Contains()` [is case sensitive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2).

Comment: @un-lucky it is case sentive

Comment: i can put  Textbox.Text because im progamming in a class